# CPanel IP Blocker - Block all IP addresses?

Tags: cpanel

I am looking into the setup of a client's CPanel server.

When I visit the IP Blocker page, there is a single entry listed (shown in image):[image]

What this tells me is that all IP addresses are blocked from accessing the server.

**Question 1**
What exactly are we blocking here? Is this simply access to the website? What this tells me is that nobody would be able to see the hosted web site. This is in fact not the case, as the site is running in production and users and using it.

**Question 2**
How can I recreate this "All" rule? What did someone enter into the text field to tell CPanel to block all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "all all all" report in cPanel's IP blocker does imply that everyone is blocked from accessing your site! However, that does not seem to be the case. I would assume that cPanel's "reporting" is perhaps in error, or rather "not entirely clear" (see below).

cPanel blocks IP addresses by simply creating the appropriate `allow from ...` and `deny from ...` directives in the root .htaccess file. Likewise, it reports the blocking "state" by scanning this file.

> How can I recreate this "All" rule?

You can manually create a `deny from all` rule in .htaccess and cPanel will report this "All" rule. I don't think you can create this in cPanel as "all" is obviously not a valid IP address.

See if you can see something similar in your .htaccess file. It might be conditional! For example, I have found that the following is enough to trigger this "All" state being reported:

```
<Files "foo.html">
deny from all
</Files>
```

This obviously does not block your entire site, however, it does block all users! cPanel's reporting is not entirely clear since it does not differentiate.

Comment: Thank god I don't rely too much on cpanel for IP management now that I read the answer. Cpanel should be blocking IP addresses right at the core (via iptables in linux or similar) so that the block works faster and apache is skipped for the bad IP's.